# Change index of array values with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

After running a function i am getting an array like this.

```
    ["1:s", "2:2", "0:f"]
```

but i want to convert this array like this

```
     ["0:f","1:s","2:2"]
```

i mean index should be same as key.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried?

Comment: please show your function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just sort it with taking the index out of the string.

```js
var array = ["1:s", "2:2", "0:f"];
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.split(':')[0] - b.split(':')[0];
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Note: first approach will be inconsistent as it sorts based on string. Try adding `"12:g"`. Second approach is ideal